# Dynamically Rendering Actions from Controller - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, controller, action, html-helper

I am trying to write some code in my MVC controller that will dynamically call another controllers action and render it as a string. Basically I am trying to use the @Html.Action() helper method that is available to razor views.

However HtmlHelper in the controller does not seem to have access to the Action method to call a controllers action and output the string.

Does anyone know how I can dynamically render a partial view into a string and then add that string to a Content result?

I do not want to do any of this logic in the razor view as it is entirely dynamic and the HTML can be completely changed depending on some configuration the user has set in the database. This means that I might want to call many different controller actions, get the string and append it to the Content result.

Any help people could give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following method ([taken from here](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/)):

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to render a view in which you could call a custom Html helper extension method in which you could use `Html.Action`:

```
public static IHtmlString MyMethod(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    // you could use html.Action("someAction", "someController") here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice implementation, is there any way how I can do this from API controller?